# curl and php problem -- blank page

Tags: php, curl

I am attempting to download images saved in a url to a local folder, and have made the following attempt at doing so with curl. I would like to know if it is necessary to include curl or download it seperateley, or if my function will just work. I would like to know if there are any obvious problems with my implementation below. I am aware of the sql vulnerability and I am switching to prepared statements. I have trimmed non relevant parts of the code for brevity.

edit: the function is out of the while loop. The page displays if I comment out the call the the function, otherwise I only get a blank page. Why is this

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
if (isset($_GET["cmd"]))

  $cmd = $_GET["cmd"];

else

  die("You should have a 'cmd' parameter in your URL");

 $pk = $_GET["pk"];

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","someuser","notreal");

if(!$con)

{

die('Connection failed because of' .mysql_error());

}
mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8'); 

mysql_select_db("somedb",$con);

if($cmd=="GetAuctionData")

{

$sql="SELECT * FROM AUCTIONS WHERE ARTICLE_NO ='$pk'";

$sql2="SELECT ARTICLE_DESC FROM AUCTIONS WHERE ARTICLE_NO ='$pk'";

$htmlset = mysql_query($sql2);

$row2 = mysql_fetch_array($htmlset);



$result = mysql_query($sql);

function savePicture($imageUrl) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $lastImg);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
    $fileContents = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $newImg = imagecreatefromstring($fileContents);
    return imagejpeg($newImg, "./{$pk}.jpg",100);
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{



$lastImg = $row['PIC_URL']; 


savePicture($lastImg);


<div id='rightlayer'>

<img src='./".$pk.".jpg' width='".$outputWidth."' height='".$outputHeight."'>


</div>

</div>

</div>";



}



}

mysql_free_result($result);
```

Comment: savePhoto() vs. savePicture()?

Comment: Why don’t you just set error_reporting to E_ALL (or better: E_STRICT) and test your script? This would be the easiest to see, if there are any errors.

Comment: I set error reporting to E_ALL, however I do not have access to the logfiles and nothing is displayed in the browser.

Comment: Use the ini_set function to set display_errors to true for runtime.

Comment: I managed to see the error log, it states undefined call to function curl_init. Do I have to include curl in a special way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’ll get an error if you declare a function inside a loop when the loop is run more than one time. So you should declare the `savePicture` function outside `while`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd take the function definition out of the while block.

In my opinion your using curl for the sake of using curl here, a simpler method would be to use [file get contents](http://php.net/file_get_contents).

Comment: I do not currently have access to access a URL as a file, which is required for file get contents is it not?